# How to access details from a method in flutter in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

These are the upload details to a Firestore document.

```dart
'uid': this._userId,
'Email': this._email,
'Fullname': this._fullname,
'Location': this._location,
'ImageUrl': this._imageurl = await uploadImage(),
```

Using the code below — if I am correct — I'm trying to access the details of current user using the `uid` code present in the document.

```dart
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

getData() async {
  return await Firestore.instance
      .collection('userdetails')
      .where('uid', isEqualTo: user)
      .getDocuments();
}
```

Now, as the method returns the document with the user details of the current user, how can I access each of the values to display on `screen.Name` and Image URL?

Comment: DocumentReference docRef = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('userdetails')
        .add(userData)
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    }); This is how I am adding data to firestore how can I add it to document of current uid. Where should I include tha in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect that code to work, since `user` is a [FirebaseUser](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser-class.html) object, and not a UID string.  You probably want this instead to use the [uid](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserInfo/uid.html) of the current user to filter the results:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('userdetails')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .getDocuments();
```

Comment: Okay, But after the details of document gets into this getData() method how to access it to display

Comment: That sounds like a whole different problem.  You should make an attempt, then post another question with the code you're using that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I did it as a separate question check it if you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to access those fields:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('userdetails').document(user.uid).get().then((doc) {
    _fullname = doc.data['Fullname'];
    _imageUrl = doc.data['ImageUrl'];
}
```